# can I use AWS step functions to wait for multiple events and a dynamodb record to exist before continuing execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

[proposed arch diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyDbx.png)

I have 2 sqs and 1 lambda , the 2 sqs stream each recieve an event at different times that relates to an order .

stream one gets the customer email and txn ID , stream 2 gets the items of the order , the lambda get invoked with the event that creates the customer in our database >

I want to use step functions to capture the order event from the first stream , wait for the second order event, and wait for the customer to exist in our database once all of these conditions are met I would like to execute some business logic on all of the information combined together .

Comment: There are a few ways to implement this sort of event aggregation with Step Functions. However, the approach you take would depend a bit on the other choices you have made in your system. Am I correct that you will have 1 SQS queue that gets a message for transaction start. Then a second that gets a message for each order. And that termination of the transaction is indicated when a record appears in a DynamoDB table for the customer? Or could the items and the existence of the customer record come out of order?

Comment: let me try to explain better.
stream 1 receives tx id and email of customer only , this happens once per txn, 
stream 2 receives the order line info for the order ,
a completley seperate system send a custom event indicating the customer should be created within our database 
these events can occur in any order 
there is no event to signify that any of the other events have happened 
I would like to kick off a step function when I receive an event on either stream 1 or stream 2 
the sf should wait for the remaining event then poll dynamo for customer

Comment: basically I would like to merge all 3 pieces of data together and send it to a 3rd party , I can make this by having a holding table with ttl but I would like to use step functions as i think it will be simpler and easier to maintain.